# elasticsearch : pagination of continuosly updating data

Tags: pagination, elasticsearch

I am new to elasticsearch.
I am listening a network traffic and index them into the elasticsearch.
But when I search it I dont want to give a size for searching.I learnt that I have to pagination but when I search, I couldnt understand and I couldnt find example.
I need some advice.
Sorry about my English and Thanks for your advices.
My search code is a Python code.

Comment: What is the code you tried ?

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that you can't see immediately the indexed data : an operation called **refresh** has to be performed (default value for search_interval is 1 second).

You can find [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/pagination.html#pagination) some documentation about pagination from the elasticsearch definitive guide.

If you have lots of data indexed constinuously (e.g. lines of logs), you could use a [scroll](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scan-scroll.html#scan-scroll) and filtering the results on the last 5 minutes for example ([here is a simple example of this filtering](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_ranges.html#_ranges_on_dates)). Then you can relaunch another scroll search for the next 5 minutes etc...